# How to Make Alert(); Show After Page is Fully Loaded?

Tags: javascript

**My Background:** I am new to Javascript. I have used a bit of Jquery before, but I am trying to learn pure vanilla Javascript without using a library.

**My Software:** I am using the latest Brackets text editor along with the latest version of Safari.

**The Problem:** I am trying to show an `alert();` after the page is fully loaded and displayed. The alert always runs before the page is displayed. The page displays only after I close the alert.

**My Research:** I have tried many different solutions, almost none of them seem to work; however, when a solution DOES work, some of my other Javascript statements stop working. I have tried the following solutions:

- Putting my script tags at the bottom of the page

  ```
  <body>
  <!--Body content-->
  <script src="javascript.js"></script>
  </body>
  ```
- Creating an unload event in my .js file

  ```
  window.onload = function(){
      alert("My alert!");
  }
  ```
- Creating a `readystatechange` event and checking the current document.readystate in my .js file

  ```
  document.onreadystatechange = function(){
      if(document.readyState=='loaded' || document.readyState=='complete')
          alert("My alert!");
  }
  ```
- I've even tried methods not involving my .js file such as

  ```
  <head>
  <script>
      function myFunction(){
          alert("My alert!");
      }
  </script>
  </head>

  <body onload="myFunction()">
  <!--Body content-->
  </body>
  ```

**Closest Answer:** The only thing close to working is putting the `async` attribute in my script tag like...

```
<script src="Javascript-101.js" async></script>
```

However, a few weird things happen when I do this:

- When I include the `async` attribute, it works! The `alert();` is shown after the page is displayed... BUT my `document.write();` statements stop working, regardless of whether I put my script in the head of my HTML document or before the closing `</body>` tag.
- When I exclude the `async` statement with my script located in the head of my HTML document, it does not work... the `alert();` is shown before the page is displayed. Additionally, it makes my `Math.sqrt(64);` statement stop working. However, my `document.write();` statements work just fine.
- When I exclude the `async` statement with my script located before the closing `</body>` tag, it does not work... the `alert();` is shown before the page is displayed. All of my other statements work just fine in this scenario.

**My HTML Code:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Javascript-101.css">
    <title>Intro to Javascript</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Javascript has front-end and server-side applications.</h1>
    </div>
    <p id="math-answer"></p>
    <script src="Javascript-101.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**My Javascript:**

```
/*jslint devel: true, evil: true*/
var message = "Welcome to my website!";
alert(message);
document.write("<h2>Text #2 goes here.</h2>");
document.write("<p>Text #3 goes here.</p>");
console.log("Hello, console!");
document.getElementById("math-answer").innerHTML = Math.sqrt(64);
```

Comment: `window.onload` should work

Comment: @Satpal To be clear, my updated Javascript should look like this right? `var message = "Welcome to my website!";
window.onload = function () {
    alert(message);
};`

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
var myFunc = function(){
  alert("My alert!");
}
:
:
window.attachEvent('onload', myFunc);
```

Answer (score 0):

By reading the [jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/ready.js) source code and further investigating the [Mozilla guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/Events/DOMContentLoaded), you should listen for the `DOMContentLoaded` event:

> The DOMContentLoaded event is fired when the initial HTML document has
>   been completely loaded and parsed, without waiting for stylesheets,
>   images, and subframes to finish loading. A very different event load
>   should be used only to detect a fully-loaded page. It is an incredibly
>   popular mistake to use load where DOMContentLoaded would be much more
>   appropriate, so be cautious.

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    console.log("DOM fully loaded and parsed");
  });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using jquery as following

```
$(window).ready(function(){
alert("lalalala");
});
```

you will see the refresh of the page anyways, but it will keep loading even after the alert is triggered. I tried using

```
$(windows).on('load', function(){
alert();
});
```

since load is deprecated already, but no luck there, it should show the alert only after the refresh is finished but is your omages are cached it wont work and wont trigger the alert so, I sticked with "ready"

Answer (score 0):

I did this and it work

in html file:

```
<body onload="myFunction()">
...
<script src="javascript.js"></script>
</body>
```

then in the separate javascript file (javascript.js) we write:

```
body.onload function myFunction() {
alert("My Alert!");
}
```

Note:

- Instead inside head tags, put the script at the last, at the bottom before the body close tag, because if the script is long, it will ensure all the body elements will fired first
- The problem, as I see it, you use "window" element, instead of "body" element in the javascript. As we know it, we must be consistent to avoid uncertainty.